# Trying to use Twilio with Meteor, ReferenceError: Twilio is not defined

Tags: javascript, meteor, npm, twilio

To preface this, I'm very new to Meteor and have never used Twilio before, so I'm probably just making a silly mistake somewhere.

I'm using the Twilio API bindings found [here](https://github.com/andreioprisan/twilio-meteor/) and trying to get a simple snippet of code working to send an SMS message within a Meteor.methods function. Here's the event trigger and method function:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.twilioPlayground.events({
        "click button": function() {
            Meteor.call("sendSMS");
        }
    });
}

Meteor.methods({
    sendSMS: function () {
        twilio = Twilio('i put my account sid here', 'and my auth token here');
        twilio.sendSms({
            to:'+7199634882', 
            from: '+17194530451', 
            body: 'This is a test'
        }, function(err, responseData) { //this function is executed when a response is received from Twilio
            if (!err) {
                console.log(responseData.from); // outputs "+14506667788"
                console.log(responseData.body); // outputs "word to your mother."
            }
        });
    }
});
```

So when that event is triggered, I'm getting the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Twilio is not defined
at Meteor.methods.sendSMS (http://localhost:3000/myTodoApp.js?8ae55884eab4c6a28ef9da8344fcf0b9d15c24ac:194:18)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:4239:25
at _.extend.withValue (http://localhost:3000/packages/meteor.js?61916b1060b33931a21f104fbffb67c2f3d493c5:945:17)
at _.extend.apply (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:4230:54)
at _.extend.call (http://localhost:3000/packages/ddp.js?1f971b2ac9f4bdab7372cb5098ed1e26ff98dfb2:4108:17)
at Object.Template.twilioPlayground.events.click button (http://localhost:3000/myTodoApp.js?8ae55884eab4c6a28ef9da8344fcf0b9d15c24ac:106:20)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:3103:18)
at http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2371:30
at Object.Blaze._withCurrentView (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2029:12)
at null.<anonymous> (http://localhost:3000/packages/blaze.js?77c0809654ee3a10dcd5a4f961fb1437e7957d33:2370:26)
```

Aside from adding the mrt:moment and mrt:twilio-meteor packages to the project, I didn't do any more setup. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You defined your method on both client and server. But the `Twilio` symbol is not even exposed on the client (because it is something client doesn't need to know about). Hence you get this error. Put your `sendSMS` method definition into `Meteor.isServer` block and it should work fine.

Comment: Makes sense. Worked perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Correct. Thanks.